# Comparison of two groups using word cloud comparison R

Tags: r, corpus, word-cloud, quanteda

Thanks in advance for your help. 
I have a CSV file in which each row is a respondent(n=612) and I would like to compare the text which is composed of responses in sentences between two columns, one describing a good experience vs. bad experience using a comparison word cloud.

```
 ##First I merged my response columns
 mydata2= mydata%>% 
 gather(response, text, Good, Bad)

mydata2$text <- sapply(mydata2$text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1","ASCII", sub=""))

mydata2<-data.frame(mydata2)

## Calculate Corpus
docs<-Corpus(VectorSource(mydata2$text)) %>%
tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
tm_map(tolower)  %>%
tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("english")) %>%
tm_map(stripWhitespace) %>%
tm_map(PlainTextDocument)

inspect(docs)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
```

However this would not let me generate a tdm. 
Is this the best way to go about comparing text variables in columns or should I generate two different corpus (one for good and one for bad) and compare them that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to do this in **quanteda**, you would:

1. Create a corpus, using `corpus()`.
2. Make sure that it contained a document variable (using `docvar <-`) associating each document with a sentiment category (good or bad).  (No need to consolidate them at this stage.)
3. Create a dfm, and group the output using the `groups =` argument with the value named as your grouping docvar.
4. Call `textplot_wordcloud(yourdfm, comparison = TRUE)` on the dfm created in the previous step.

To demonstrate this on a reproducible example using the built-in `data_corpus_inaugural` corpus object:

```
library("quanteda")
obama_trump_dfm <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
    corpus_subset(President %in% c("Obama", "Trump")) %>%
    dfm(remove = stopwords("english"), remove_punct = TRUE, groups = "President") %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 3)

textplot_wordcloud(obama_trump_dfm, comparison = TRUE, 
                   max_words = 100, color = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

In this example, the corpus is subsetted on its docvar `President` to select only Obama and Trump; then the dfm is created with stopwords and punctuation removed, and grouped according to President; and then words with frequencies less than 3 are removed.  That dfm is then sent to `textplot_wordcloud()` with the comparison flag set to TRUE, and a maximum of 100 words plotted.  The colours are also set.